# Преобразовать JSON в объект

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jackson

Ко мне приходит JSON файл:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "date":1586763078,
   "params":{
      "A":"0",
      "B":"1",
      "C":"2",
      "D":"3",
   }
}
```

Сохраняю его в виде объекта следующим способом:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
MyObject jsonObj = mapper.readValue(result, MyObject.class);
```

Класс MyObject:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyObject{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private long id;
    private Timestamp date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myobject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Param> params;
}
```

Класс Param:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Param{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private double count;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private MyObject myObject;
}
```

Во время преобразования выходит ошибка "Unrecognized field "A"".
Насколько я понял jackson хочет, что бы я определил поле "А" в классе "Param", но мне это не нужно. Я хочу, что бы в объекте класса MyObject хранился массив объектов Param у которого всего 2 поля (имя и значение). Таких параметров может быть много.
Как настроить jackson, что бы он воспринимал параметр "А" не как отдельное поле, а как строку для класса Param ?

Comment: Используйте `Map` и не изобретайте велосипед. Или же делайте свой `Serializer/Desializer` для нужного преобразования.

Comment: А как можно переделать этот код под Map ?